# Cannot start Redmine server

Tags: redmine

I am using Redmine version 2.5.2 Stable.

After a server crash, we rebooted our server and found that redmine is not starting.

When I start rails using command `rails s`, I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:233:in `activate': can't activate rack (~> 1.4.5, runtime) for ["actionpack-3.2.18", "railties-3.2.18"], already activated rack-1.6.0.beta for ["rack-ssl-1.3.4", "railties-3.2.18"] (Gem::LoadError)
            from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:249:in `activate'
            from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `each'
            from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `activate'
            from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:249:in `activate'
            from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `each'
            from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `activate'
            from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1082:in `gem'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/rails:22
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15
```

Please find my gem list

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.18, 3.2.17)
actionpack (3.2.18, 3.2.17)
activemodel (3.2.18, 3.2.17)
activerecord (3.2.18, 3.2.17)
activeresource (3.2.18, 3.2.17)
activesupport (3.2.18, 3.2.17)
acts-as-taggable-on (2.3.3)
arel (3.0.3)
awesome_nested_set (2.1.6)
builder (3.0.4, 3.0.0)
bundler (1.9.2, 1.7.3)
capybara (2.1.0)
childprocess (0.5.3)
coderay (1.1.0, 1.0.9)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
commonjs (0.2.7)
daemon_controller (1.2.0)
daemons (1.1.9)
delayed_job (4.0.6)
delayed_job_active_record (4.0.3)
diff-lcs (1.2.5)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (1.0.3)
execjs (2.5.2, 2.0.2)
faraday (0.8.8)
fastercsv (1.5.5)
ffi (1.9.3)
git (1.2.9.1)
hashie (2.0.5)
hike (1.2.3)
httpauth (0.2.0)
i18n (0.7.0, 0.6.11, 0.6.9)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (3.0.4, 2.0.3)
jquery-ui-rails (5.0.3, 5.0.2)
json (1.8.2, 1.8.1)
jwt (0.1.8)
less (2.3.3)
less-rails (2.3.3)
less-rails-bootstrap (2.3.3)
libv8 (3.11.8.17 x86_64-linux, 3.11.8.13 x86_64-linux)
liquid (2.4.1)
mail (2.5.4)
metaclass (0.0.4)
method_source (0.8.1)
mime-types (1.25.1)
mini_portile (0.6.0)
mocha (1.1.0)
money (5.0.0)
multi_json (1.11.0, 1.10.1, 1.10.0)
multipart-post (1.2.0)
mysql2 (0.3.18, 0.3.16)
net-ldap (0.3.1)
node (0.0.2)
nokogiri (1.6.3.1)
oauth2 (0.8.1)
omniauth (1.1.4)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.1)
omniauth-shopify-oauth2 (1.1.2)
passenger (5.0.6, 4.0.50)
pg (0.16.0)
polyglot (0.3.5, 0.3.4)
pry (0.9.12.2)
pry-rails (0.3.1)
quiet_assets (1.0.2)
rack (1.6.0.beta, 1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-openid (1.4.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.4)
rack-test (0.6.3, 0.6.2)
rails (3.2.18, 3.2.17)
railties (3.2.18, 3.2.17)
rake (10.4.2, 10.3.2, 10.3.1)
rdoc (3.12.2)
redcarpet (2.3.0)
RedCloth (3.0.4)
ref (1.0.5, 1.0.2)
render_parent (0.0.5)
rmagick (2.14.0, 2.13.3)
rspec (3.2.0)
rspec-core (3.2.3)
rspec-expectations (3.2.1)
rspec-mocks (3.2.1)
rspec-support (3.2.2)
ruby-ole (1.2.11.8)
ruby-openid (2.3.0)
rubyzip (1.1.6)
sass (3.3.7)
sass-rails (3.2.6)
selenium-webdriver (2.43.0)
shopify_api (3.0.3)
shopify_app (4.2.3)
shoulda (3.3.2)
shoulda-context (1.0.2)
shoulda-matchers (1.4.1)
slim (3.0.3)
slop (3.4.5)
spreadsheet (0.6.9)
sprockets (2.2.3, 2.2.2)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)
state_machine (1.2.0)
temple (0.7.5)
therubyracer (0.11.4)
thor (0.19.1)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.15)
tzinfo (0.3.43, 0.3.41, 0.3.39)
vcard (0.2.12)
webrat (0.7.3)
websocket (1.2.1)
will_paginate (3.0.7)
xpath (2.0.0)
yard (0.8.7.4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of your packages need `rack (~> 1.4.5, runtime)` so remove the beta version that you've installed and install the stable version 1.4.5 then you can start your rails project.